# Image gallery - Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

I am making my Image gallery using Jquery Mobile. I have successfully created something as in this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/NV6Py/).  I replace the Image instead of the 'article' in the code like this...

```
> <image data-role="page" id="article1">
>     <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
>       <h1>Image1</h1>
>     </div>
>     <div data-role="content">
>       <img src=im1.jpg/>
>     </div>
>     <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
>       <h1>Footer</h1>    
>     </div>   </Image>
```

Now I need the images on the right and left of the "Image" that I have replaced. And It should use swipe events too.. Can anyone tell me how can I go about it?